# How to change color of tableview background

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to figure how to change the color of the background of a plain uitableview after the using has scrolled past the top or bottom of the table. Not sure what its called but if you look at the mail app, if you scroll down, whilst already at the top of the table, the background is a dark gray color with a slight gradient. Anyone know how i go about implementing this?

Comment: this is duplicate of many   http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+change+color+of+tableview+background  right here in stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

will provide a red color background for your table view

Other options include

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:anImage];
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: green: blue: alpha: ];
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue: saturation: brightness: alpha: ];
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:cgColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // you can write any color in place of clear color
```